# Sorting a for-each using another node set with a common id

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I'm hoping to sort a table generated by a for-each. The data which determins the sort is not contained within the for-each node set,  but is instead contained within . There is a common_id between the  node set and the  node set. I've tried assigning the common_id to a local variable within the for-each but the sort cannot see it. Is there a way to achieve this? Some examples below.

Example XML

```
<root>
  <seq>
    <common_id>B1U3</common_id>
    <seq_data>1</seq_data>
  </seq>
  <seq>
    <common_id>R3D</common_id>
    <seq_data>3</seq_data>
  </seq>
  <seq>
    <common_id>Y3110W</common_id>
    <seq_data>2</seq_data>
  </seq>

  <detail>
    <common_id>Y3110W</common_id>
    <other_data>spame</other_data>
  </detail>
  <detail>
    <common_id>B1U3</common_id>
    <other_data>spamo</other_data>
  </detail>
  <detail>
    <common_id>R3D</common_id>
    <other_data>spama</other_data>
  </detail>
</root>
```

Required Output

```
____________________________    
¦Common Id      ¦Other Data¦
¦---------------¦----------¦
¦B1U3           ¦spama     ¦
¦Y3110W         ¦spame     ¦
¦R3d            ¦spamo     ¦
¦_______________¦__________¦
```

Current XSLT

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <table>
    <tr>
        <td>Common ID</td>
        <td>Other Data</td>
    </tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="detail">
      <xsl:variable name="local_id" select="common_id"/>
      <xsl:sort select="../seq[common_id = $local_id]/seq_data"/>
        <tr>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="common_id"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="other_data"/></td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it work if you use the `current()` function instead of the variable?  Also you probably want to make the sort numeric rather than lexicographic:

```
<xsl:sort select="../seq[common_id = current()/common_id]/seq_data"
          data-type="number"/>
```

Comment: Using your `xsl:sort` and changing the match of the template to `match="/root"` should work fine. +1

Comment: That has worked to perfection. I knew there would be a "current()" functionality just couldn't find it in the docs. Thank-you!

Comment: Yes, it's a bit of an oddity - it's a function for use in XPath expressions but it's documented in the XSLT spec rather than the XPath one.